# Visual Studio autocompletion doesn't work when backspace used during typing

Tags: autocomplete

I have this annoying problem where when I type something in Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 version 15.9.16 and make a spelling mistake and delete wrong characters using backspace it stops displaying a window with autocompletion results. Is there a way of fixing it? 
For instance:

- Start typing: glVertexAttribPoinert (suggestions are showing)
- Delete to: glVertexAttrib (no suggestions, pressing tab moves carret. Will
  not show other options)

Comment: Who were you DenverCoder9? What did you see?